# Konik ZUGFeRD PaymentDiscountTerms

Tags: invoice, zugferd

I am testing konik.io Library using .NET.
I want to setup payment discount for an invoice. I thought I could do this with the class `PaymentDiscountTerms`:

```
var paymentDiscountTerm = new PaymentDiscountTerms();
paymentDiscountTerm.setBasis(DiscountAmount, CurrencyCode.EUR));
```

But this seems not possible - the compiler outputs an error message: **paymentDiscountTerm.setBasis is inaccessible due to its protection level**

What is going wrong? How is discount managed otherwise?

UPDATE: I found a similar issue at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/konik-io/88z6KyQkX5U